# Multiple counts in one SQL query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm building a web application with CodeIgniter.

Users can "love" or "hate" posts. These actions are stored in a table called post_rating with the following columns:

- id
- post_id
- user_id
- rating

Rating can either be 0 for neutral, 1 for love or 2 for hate.

In my model, I have returned some basic information for each post with the following function:

```
function get_posts($thread_id)

{

    $this->db->select('id, user_id, date_posted, content');
    $this->db->from('post');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)

    {

        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

I understand I need to join the post_rating table, but how would I go about also returning the love and hate counts in the same array as the title, content etc?

Thanks!

:)

**UPDATE!**

Here is my MODEL at the moment:

```
function get_posts($thread_id)

{

    $this->db->select('post.id, post.user_id, post.date_posted, post.content, post.status_visible, user.username, user.location, user.psn, user.clan, user.critic, user.pro, SUM(case when rating = 1 then 1 end) as love, SUM(case when rating = 2 then 1 end) as hate');
    $this->db->from('post');
    $this->db->join('user', 'user.id = post.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('post_rating', 'post_rating.post_id = post.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
    $this->db->order_by('date_posted', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)

    {

        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from('post_vote');

        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

Comment: A more sensible rating scheme would be 0 for neutral, 1 for love and -1 for hate.

Comment: Good call. I might switch it over. Thanks!

Comment: Not much difference in this query, but you may find `SUM(rating)` useful later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` to sum up two different stats:

```
select  title
,       content
,       sum(case when pr.rating = 1 then 1 end) as Love
,       sum(case when pr.rating = 2 then 1 end) as Hate
,       (
        select  count(*)
        from    posts up
        where   up.user_id = p.user_id
        ) as UserPostCount
from    posts p
left join
        posts_rating pr
on      pr.post_id = p.post_id
group by
        title
,       content
,       user_id
```

Comment: Funny thing, we posted two slightly different solutions at the exact same time (up to seconds precision)

Comment: Thanks, mate. It's working, but now it's only returning one post (it was returning all of them before). I've updated the OP with my current model. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tim: add `group by p.post_id`

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but how would I also return a count of the user's total post count in the same query? I tried adding "SUM(case when post.user_id = post.user_id then 1 end) as posts" to the end of my select statement but the post count is always 1. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use a subquery for that, added to the answer.  If the subquery uses `user_id`, `user_id` has to be part of the `group by`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select p.post_id, 
       max(p.title) title,
       count(case pr.rating when 1 then 1 else null end) lovecount,
       count(case pr.rating when 2 then 1 else null end) hatecount
from YourPostsTable p 
left join post_rating pr on p.post_id = pr.post_id
group by p.post_id
```